# How to set column value in SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I want to set one column value in all rows to "0"

```
 SqlCommand cmd = m_objDbCAPEX.GetSqlCommand(CommandType.Text);

 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CAPEX_BillOfMaterialItem.* FROM CAPEX_BillOfMaterialItem,CAPEX_BillOfMaterial WHERE CAPEX_BillOfMaterialItem.szBillOfMaterialId = CAPEX_BillOfMaterial.szBillOfMaterialId and CAPEX_BillOfMaterial.szProjectCode = '" + szProjectCode + "'";

 da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 da.Fill(dtDat);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a point to @Rahul's answer.

If the field has specific values and if you want that alone to make it to 0 then you need CASE statements.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN capex_billofmaterialitem.fieldname = 'checking value goes here' 
       THEN 0 
         ELSE capex_billofmaterialitem.fieldname 
       END AS fieldname1, 
       capex_billofmaterialitem.* 
FROM   capex_billofmaterialitem, 
       capex_billofmaterial 
WHERE  capex_billofmaterialitem.szbillofmaterialid = 
              capex_billofmaterial.szbillofmaterialid 
       AND capex_billofmaterial.szprojectcode = '" + szProjectCode + "'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try to set it like this:

```
select 0 as fieldName, col1, col2,...  from yourTable
```

In this case your `fieldName` column will be set as 0. (*You can replace the actual name of the column with fieldName*)